# Run commands through Shell Scripts in linux

Tags: linux, backup, sh, cp

I'd like to set up a `backup.sh` file that executes these two commands when run:

```
cp ~/SURV/plugins/iConomy/accounts.mini ~/backups/

cp ~/SURV/plugins/CoreProtect/database.db ~/backups/
```

I want it to just run these 2 commands and display the text *"Backups creados con éxito!"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` between commands: it will execute the next command only if the previous command execution is a success. The `||` does the inverse => `echo "error"` will be displayed if one of the both `cp` fails.

```
#!/bin/sh 
cp ~/SURV/plugins/iConomy/accounts.mini   ~/backups/ &&
cp ~/SURV/plugins/CoreProtect/database.db ~/backups/ &&
echo "Backups creados con éxito!" ||
echo "error"
```

You can also add `-v` option to the `cp` command for more visibility.

In order to make your script executable you have to do:

```
chmod +x backup.sh
```

Comment: I am happy you like it. Do not forget to vote up please ;-) cheers